# Find parent of b tag having textvalue without id and class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's My code:

```
<div templateid="asd">
   <b>SEND</b>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the parent div having b tag text as SEND.and then binding another DOM to the parent div.I cannot give id class or any other attributes to above tag as its an external web application with which i'm trying to integrate our application.

and what i tried is:

```
 $('div').find('b[html="SEND"]');
 $('div').find('b[text="SEND"]');
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for stopping by...!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try

```
$("b:contains('SEND')").parent()
```

Or a mixture of everyone's answers:

```
$('b').filter(':contains("SEND")').closest('div')
```

Comment: It should do - check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/HBWYF/ you will see the parent div has been selected and turned red using the above

Comment: The `b` tag selector is important as ["The matching text can appear directly within the selected element, in any of that element's descendants, or a combination thereof."](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: edited answer to show new selector or is that going to give you the same result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "contains" like this:

```
$("b:contains('SEND')").closest('div')
```

Comment: Oops, I think I misunderstood you're question.  I've edited my response to use closest('div') which will get the closest parent div element.  Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Use **[filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**

`$('div').find('b').filter(':contains("SEND")').parent();`